# For what functions $f$, $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ where $X$ is a gamma random variable, is known?

Tags: probability, reference-request

Frequently, when solving different statistical modeling problems, I need to compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ where $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ is a gamma random variable.

For $f(x) = x^n$, this is well-studies and can be easily computed using the moment generating function.

I'm interested in references for different classes of functions $f$ for which this expectation is either known in the form of an analytic function, or can be expresses using well-known functions (beta functions, incomplete gamma functions, error functions, etc.)

Comment: When $\alpha$ are positive integers, the question essentially boils down to investigating the derivatives of the Laplace transform of $f$. Now we may use the vast literature on Laplace transform...